# Operating on complex numbers when the source signal is just a real number

Tags: math, fft, complex-numbers

I have a sequence of real numbers and I want to compute the FFT on it. The FFT function requires complex numbers.

So can I set the imaginary value to 0 and compute the FFT?

Next question is when I get the result values (frequency domain values), they are in complex format.

If I do the inverse of the FFT on these complex values, can I discard the imaginary component and use just real part of the result?

Comment: A slight alternative is cosine transforms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the real parts of your complex input to the signal sample values and the imaginary parts to zero. Alternatively you can use a real-to-complex FFT, which may also be a little faster than a normal complex-to-complex FFT.

As for the inverse FFT - so long as your frequency domain complex values have complex conjugate symmetry (which they will have if your input is purely real), then the IFFT will give you a purely real time domain signal again. If you modify your frequency domain values prior to the IFFT then make sure you maintain the complex conjugate symmetry. Again you can also consider using a complex-to-real IFFT, which may be more efficient and will relieve you of the job of maintaining the symmetry.

Comment: Paul, thanks... followup...  (1) Where can I find real to complex FFT and complex to real iFFT?  (2) in my current usage, I am guessing that since I do not modify the frequency between the FFT and iFFT, I can happily ignore the imaginary parts in the iFFT result?

Comment: If you don't modify the frequency domain data then you'll just get back your original time domain signal (with imaginary components being zero) - however that's a little pointless - why go to the frequency domain and back ? As for real-to-complex FFTs and complex-to-real IFFTs - most FFT packages have these, e.g. FFTW, KissFFT, Accelerate, etc - what OS/platform/programming language/FFT package are you using ?

Comment: I am actually seeing some minimal imaginary values in the return... they are small, but non zero.  The reason I am doing this in the first place is that the only noise cancellation algorithm I have operates in frequency domain.  I am using Xcode on MAC-OSx

Comment: Yes, you may well see the effects of finite floating point precision, particularly if you are only using single precision floats, but as you  have seen, these values are sufficiently close to zero that they can be treated as zero. If you're using Mac OS X then the FFTs in the Accelerate framework should give you everything you need.

Answer (score 1):

For this type of math, a real number IS just a complex number with an (assumed or explicit) imaginary part equal to zero.

If the frequency data you feed an IFFT computation is conjugate symmetric, then the imaginary values in the result will be tiny compared to the real values, mostly numerical noise from using finite precision arithmetic.  If you understand significant digits of precision, you will note that these values all round to zero for any reasonable or useful precision.